# Do I add salesforce SPF record to my domain itself?

Tags: email, outlook, salesforce, spf

I am having some issues with emails that are being sent from SF. Therefore, I am wanting to add SF's SPF record. Do I add this to my domain itself? For example, my domain is hosted from networksolutions. I go there and add the SF spf record, correct?

If so, I am having a little bit of trouble figuring out exactly where I would put the spf record in the fields. I am referrencing this help article.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Sender-Policy-Framework-SPF-and-Salesforce-SPF-Record&language=en_US&type=1

What would I put in the host? SF is sending out the mail from an email structured as example.com . There is no subdomain like help.example.com.

Would I just put `v=spf1 mx include:_spf.salesforce.com ~all` in the text field?

For the host, do I put what my mxrecord is, which is: `example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com`

And have this image from network solutions.

[image]

Comment: did your issue get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want assuming that you send outgoing email "from" ONLY salesforce and Office 365. If there are other outgoing providers (e.g., an ESP), then you need to add them as well. This would be in the root domain assuming you send *from* the root domain (aka `@`).

`v=spf1 include:_spf.salesforce.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all`

Notes:

• You don't need the mx mechanism as that creates additional DNS lookups toward the upper limit allowed for an SPF record (10 lookups)

• Make sure that you validate your SPF record. The concern here is to keep the number of DNS lookups under 10 to pass. Use the [SPF Survey.](https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/)
• Considering doing DKIM and DMARC as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I dont understand your answer.. where do you put the v=spf1 field?? In Salesforce, in localhost, company's whitelist address?

Comment: @compski The SPF record would be a TXT record in the DNS for the sending domain.